# php array of objects to json object display in proper format

Tags: jquery, json

Currently, I have PHP array of objects like below :-

```
Array
(
[0] => CLocation Object
(
[m_arrobjProblems:protected] => Array
(
[498626] => CProblem Object
(
[m_strName:protected] => 10
[m_strProblemName:protected] => Baseboard
[m_intLocationId:protected] => 45750
[m_intProblemId:protected] => 498626
[m_strMaintenanceLocationName:protected] => 10
[m_intId:protected] => 273629
[m_intCid:protected] => 4581
[m_intInspectionFormId:protected] => 15280
[m_intInspectionFormLocationId:protected] => 12864
[505934] => CLocationProblem Object
(
[m_strName:protected] => 10
[m_strProblemName:protected] => 123 
[m_intLocationId:protected] => 45750
[m_intProblemId:protected] => 505934
[m_intMaintenanceLocationId:protected] => 
[m_strMaintenanceLocationName:protected] => 10
[m_intId:protected] => 273630
[m_intCid:protected] => 4581
[m_intInspectionFormId:protected] => 15280
[m_intInspectionFormLocationId:protected] => 12864
[m_intOrderNum:protected] => 273624
[m_intDeletedBy:protected] => 
))
```

Have a requirement that needs to pass this array of object to js file so I did it following like this:-

```
inspectionFormLocations = $.parseJSON( '{$locations|json_encode}' );
```

Its showing me like this - 
{}

```
__proto__:
constructor: ƒ Object()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

How do I get php object in proper way so that I can verify the data.

Comment: Please clarify how you are encoding the object to json. Are you using anything beyond plain PHP?

Comment: I m using smarty to pass php variable to js. js file is called in smarty template file.